# PrestaShop PHP Copy files

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I am making an module in PrestaShop and i want on install of the module to copy image from one location to another in php. In the module i made

```
public function install()

{
    include(dirname(__FILE__).'/install.php');
```

And in install.php i tried:

```
copy("./folder1/image.jpg","../../folder2/folder3/image.jpg");
```

and also

```
Tools:copy("./folder1/image.jpg","../../folder2/folder3/image.jpg");
```

Dosn't work.

Comment: What does "dosn't work" mean? Is there any error message given? Have you checked all permissions?

Comment: Did you create the directories before tring to copy the file? ([Read here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#111833))

Comment: Directories already exist. When i use Tools::copy no error is given and it dosn't copy the files. When i use echo copy it gives error "cannot find such file" but the path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. Need to make it like this in main module php

```
public function CopyImages() 
{
    Tools::Copy (_PS_MODULE_DIR_ .'mymodlue/views/img/image1.jpg',_PS_MODULE_DIR_ .'modulefolder/folder1/folder2/image1.jpg');
}
```

Then in:

```
public function install()

{
    $this->CopyImages();
```